# How to display images in files folder from dreamfactory using php

Tags: php, html, dreamfactory

I have uploaded images files in folder of Dreamfactory

```
<img src="https://motodev.spotya.online/api/v2/files/Posts/posts_1508937621_Tulips.jpg">
```

Error Displayed,

> {"error":{"code":400,"context":null,"message":"No session token (JWT)
>   or API Key detected in request.."}

Comment: The error messages tells you exactly what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `files` endpoint in dreamfactory is secured. You need to provide API key or JWT token to access the files inside this directory. Another way is to add guest access to your `files` endpoint, as described [here](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Setting_up_guest_access).

You need to generate url like `https://example.org/api/v2/files/image.jpg?api_key=<your api key>`. For example:

```
<?php

// your guest API key
$apiKey = 'your api key should be here';
// your file URL
$baseUrl = 'https://example.org/api/v2/files/image.jpg';
// resulted URL
$finalUrl = $baseUrl . http_build_query(['api_key' => $apiKey]);

?>

<img src="<?= $finalUrl ?>">
```

Comment: how should i provide API key to the image source.